# Javascript function executed on page load in Devexpress

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

Can someone help me with my test environment for calling Javascript function through external file in DevExpress?

In my root.aspx, I included my external Javascript as you may see below:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Root.master.cs" Inherits="TestProjects.RootMaster" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Content/Site.css" />
     <script type="text/javascript" src="Script/TestJS.js" id="dxss_SOMECODE"> </script>
</head>
```

And in my content page I have this code:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Light.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="testPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestProjects.WebForm1" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <p>


</p>
<dx:ASPxFormLayout ID="ASPxFormLayout1" runat="server">
    <Items>
        <dx:LayoutItem>
            <LayoutItemNestedControlCollection>
                <dx:LayoutItemNestedControlContainer runat="server">
                    <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="ASPxFormLayout1_E1" runat="server">
                        <ClientSideEvents TextChanged="jsAlert()" />
                    </dx:ASPxTextBox>
                </dx:LayoutItemNestedControlContainer>
            </LayoutItemNestedControlCollection>
        </dx:LayoutItem>
    </Items>
</dx:ASPxFormLayout>

</asp:Content>
```

And in my Javascript file I have this code:

```
function jsAlert(s,e)
{
    alert("just a test");

}
```

My problem occurs when I run the page, it displayed the alert even though I didn't put any changes in the textbox, but when I do put some changes it would display error. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my coding?

Thanks.

Comment: Remove the parentheses from the TextChanged attribute

Comment: still the same, no changes happened

Comment: `<ClientSideEvents TextChanged="jsAlert" />` must work

Comment: hey albert thank you. It works now like magic. Amazing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this;

```
<ClientSideEvents TextChanged="function(s, e) { alert('just a test'); }" />
```

Or;

```
<ClientSideEvents TextChanged="function(s, e) { jsAlert(s,e); }" />
```

Comment: Yes, and it work since that is the standard code given by DevExpress when you put client side events in its objects. But I want my Javascript functions to be kept on one file, that is why I want to access it outside.